# How to get a stream with ffmpeg through a specific eth(interface)

Tags: ffmpeg, ethernet, streaming, video-streaming, multicast

I have a server with 2 interfaces, eth0 and eth1.
eth0 -> conected to Managment Switch
eth1 -> conectated to Video Switch

I would like to get a multicast with ffmpeg through eth1.

Is there some command like ffmpeg eth1 -i udp://236.1.1.1:5000  ?
I also need to know how to send the multicast through the same interface like ffmpeg eth1 udp://236.1.1.1:5000 eth1 -f mpegts udp://239.1.1.1:5000?pkt_size=188

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
udp://236.1.1.1:5000?pkt_size=188&localaddr=192.168.0.20
```

[source](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp)

Comment: Where are you getting ``192.168.0.20`` from? Please explain.

Comment: Sorry for unclearity, it is the IP address of the interface you would like to sent multicast traffic via

Comment: This worked for me -- see the documentation here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp

You can find your network interface's IP address via ifconfig

Comment: Thanks @vayvanne!