# Multicast from LAN to WAN

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, udp, multicast

I'm trying to transmit a multicast stream over the WAN.

I know the NAT cannot allow this. For this purpose, I tried to use one Raspberry with two Ethernet interfaces: The internal one and another one connected through the USB port. So `eth0` is the WAN port and `eth1` is the LAN port.

I'm using FFMPEG on a Raspberry Pi with the following command:

```
sudo ffmpeg -i http://192.168.0.61:8001/test -c copy -f mpegts "udp://224.0.0.1:1234?ttl=13"
```

The output is the following:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.16-1+deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1+deb9u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x141dd90] no frame!
[mp3 @ 0x1420c10] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x1438950] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x14394e0] Header missing
[mpegts @ 0x141a570] Could not find codec parameters for stream 6 (Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 0x141a570] Could not find codec parameters for stream 7 (Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 0x141a570] Could not find codec parameters for stream 8 (Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://192.168.0.61:8001/1:0:19:547:A3:217C:EEEE0000:0:0:0:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 100956.016789, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1351
    Stream #0:0[0xc9]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x12c](ita): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x12d](oth): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x191](oth): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, s16p, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x1f5](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:5[0x259](ita,ita,eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 492x250
    Stream #0:6[0x7d2]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:7[0xbba]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
    Stream #0:8[0xc1d]: Unknown: none ([12][0][0][0] / 0x000C)
  Program 1352
  Program 1353
  Program 1360
  Program 1361
  Program 1362
  Program 1363
  Program 1364
  Program 1365
  Program 1366
  Program 1368
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://224.0.0.1:1234?ttl=13':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1(ita): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  295 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4840kB time=00:00:07.96 bitrate=4978.4kbits/s speed=11.8x
video:4285kB audio:175kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.534529%
```

I checked with the command:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 dst port 1234

15:20:14.227868 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.227977 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.228077 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.228174 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.228281 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.228372 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.228456 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.228538 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.228617 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 1472
15:20:14.228692 IP 192.168.1.251.42236 > all-systems.mcast.net.1234: UDP, length 288
```

that the packets are actually transmitted on `eth0` but I cannot see the video using VLC.

What's the possible cause of this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a side note, but you might want to read up on which IPv4 multicast addresses are appropriate for which purposes. Video streaming to the all-hosts multicast address (224.0.0.1) doesn't seem like a good idea, because it will waste time on hosts that aren't interested in your video stream.

Answer (score 1):

In your log we can see

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://192.168.0.61:8001/1:0:19:547:A3:217C:EEEE0000:0:0:0:':
```

Which looks like an IP and specific network interface. I think what you are asking is if you can manually set the output network interface, which you can.
I suggest looking at the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp).

That link will take you to the FFmpeg documentation and should skip to the UDP section. If not, `CTRL + F` and type in `interface`. This is the main line / command of interest.

```
localaddr=addr
Local IP address of a network interface used for sending packets or joining multicast groups.
```

You can take a look at this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1393384/how-to-get-a-stream-with-ffmpeg-through-a-specific-ethinterface) for another example.